# How to access data after a command with a Telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am using pytelegrambotapi and I want to access word after the command.

```
import telebot

wordlist = {}

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6515388014:AAEQLxcO6ndqHZJyulKPCVjkvnp2Zndqumg')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi, this bot currently does nothing')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add_word(message, word):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Add the word {word} to the word list?')

@bot.message_handler()
def meme(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'мирон':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'шашки')

bot.infinity_polling()
```

> This code does not work. Even if you write a word after the command (/add someword), you get an error that says "Only 1 argument was given" So I was wondering if there is any way to do so.

I tried adding another argument to the function, but that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the text after the command with `message.text`.

Try this:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add_word(message):
    word = message.text.split(" ")[0]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Add the word {word} to the word list?')
```